# Random level function in skip list

Tags: java

I am looking at [skip list implementation in Java](http://en.literateprograms.org/Skip_list_%28Java%29) , and I am wondering the purpose of the following method:

```
public static int randomLevel() {
    int lvl = (int)(Math.log(1.-Math.random())/Math.log(1.-P));
    return Math.min(lvl, MAX_LEVEL);
}
```

And what the difference between the above method and

```
Random.nextInt(6);
```

Can anyone explain that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Random.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) should provide a random variable whose probability distribution is (approximately) a [discrete uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)) over the interval *[0, 6)*.
You can learn more about this [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discrete+uniform+distribution+%5B0%2C6%29).
http://puu.sh/XMwn

Note that internally `Random` uses a [*linear congruential generator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) where [*m = 2^48*, *a = 25214903917*, and *c = 11*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use).

---

`randomLevel` instead (approximately) uses a [*geometric distribution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) where *p* = *0.5*. You can learn more about the distribution [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=geometric+distribution+for+p%3D0.5).

http://puu.sh/XMwT

Essentially, `randomLevel` returns `0` with probability *0.5*, `1` with *0.25*, `2` with *0.125*, etc. until `6` with *0.5^7* i.e. *0.0078125** -- **far different than the *~0.14* from `Random.nextInt`**.

---

Now the importance of this is that [a skip list is an inherently *probabilistic* data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). By utilizing multiple **sparse** levels of linked lists, they can achieve average runtime performance of *O(log n)* search -- similar to a balanced binary search tree, but **less complex** and using **less space**. [Using a uniform distribution here would **not** be appropriate](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/341/fall01/Lectures/SkipLists/skip_lists/skip_lists.html#SECTION00020000000000000000), seeing how to as higher levels are less densely populated in comparison to lower ones (**note**: below, the levels grow downward) -- which is necessary for the fast searches.

[image]

Comment: According to geometric distribution formula, level should be int lvl = (int)(Math.log(Math.random()/p)/Math.log(1.-P)) instead of int lvl = (int)(Math.log(1.-Math.random())/Math.log(1.-P));
whats the reason?

Comment: The cdf is `F(k) = 1 - (1 - p)^k`, so we find `k = log (1 - F(k)) / log (1 - p)`

Answer (score 1):

Just like the link says...

"This gives us a 50% chance of the random_level() function returning 0, a 25% chance of returning 1, a 12.5% chance of returning 2 and so on..." The distribution is therefore not even.  However, Random.nextInt() is.  There is an equal likelihood that any number between 0 and 5 will be selected.

I haven't looked at the full implementation, but what probably happens is that randomLevel() us used to select a number, say n.  Then, the element that needs to be added to the skiplist will have pointers 0, 1,...,n.  You can think of each level as a separate list.

Why use a distribution like this?  Well an even distribution will require too much memory for the benefit that it will have.  By reducing the chance using a geometric distribution, the "sweet" spot is attained.  Now the advantage of obtaining a value quickly, with a smaller memory footprint is realised.